# GCP disk quota at 100% even though I don't have any disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

My current usage percentage for the quota "Persistent Disk Standard (GB)" in region "europe-west3-b" is almost at 100% even though I don't have any disks or instances created. This issue prevents me of creating any instance in this region because I get a quota exceeded error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?